# Why does CSS Hyphenation not work in IE11 and MS Edge Legacy?

Tags: css, windows, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, css-hyphens

I am working on a intranet portal for a large company in Germany.
Since in big companies tech processes sometimes run a bit slower, they still use IE11 and the old MS Edge browser.

Since these old browsers support CSS hyphens: auto (See: https://caniuse.com/css-hyphens), I developed a little CSS, which enables CSS hypens:

```
.hyphens {
    hyphens: auto;
    -ms-hyphens: auto;
}
```

So wherever I set class "hyphens", CSS hyphens shall get activated.

This works in my computer's installations of IE11 and legacy Edge, but not on my customer's clients. Neither in their Edge nor IE11 browsers.

I checked that on those computers CSS gets correctly loaded. If I add a rule like

```
background: red;
```

to class "hyphens", it gets correctly applied. Just hyphenation doesn't get applied.

I found out that on my local Edge version differs from the one my customer has.
I use Edge and IE11 in Versions

> Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1098.0
> Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134
> IE11: 11.1667.17134.0

whereas my customer has

> Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0
> Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763
> IE11: 11.1457.17763.0

installed.

We all use Windpw 10 and have German set as primary language (I think both IE11 and Edge use OS language, no separate browser language).

I tested with HTML language attribute set and not set. No difference for me (both cases working), no difference for my customer (both cases not working).

At the moment I have no idea left, why hyphens only seem to work on my machine.
Is there maybe some setting I am not aware?
Any hint how I can debug that?
Is it possible that they get (de)activated via Windows group policy?

Regards and many thanks.

Comment: Your client may be missing hyphenation dictionaries for the legacy MS browsers, e.g. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40289

Comment: That's a good point. I just found out that spell checking in HTML textareas work in my IE11/Edge installations, whereas on one of my customer's computer spell checking doesn't work.
How can I check whether or which dictionaries IE11/Edge do have installed? I guess its buried somewhere in Windows settings?

Comment: Did you try to make a test with the language attribute? If not, I suggest trying to make a test by adding `<html lang="en">` in the code and see whether it works or not.

Comment: Indeed, I tested with `<html lang="en">`, did not make any difference for my customer's client PCs.

Comment: I did some more research and found that hyphens required this code. You can also try to make a test with it and check the result. `<meta charset="utf-8">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="fr-FR">`

Answer (score 3):

Your client may be missing the hyphenation dictionaries for the legacy MS browsers.

Unfortunately I am not aware of Windows Update packages which are actually supported for installation directly in Windows 10; the MSU packages with the spell checkers for IE 11 (KB2841134) seem to be the most recent ones available for download but they cannot be installed directly ("The update is not applicable to your computer").

However, it seems that the dictionaries can be deployed via file copy. Each dictionary consists of three files with the names `MsSp7xx.alc`, `MsSp7xx.dub` and `MsSp7xx.lex`, where `xx` is the language code (e.g. `en-US` or `de` etc.).

The dictionaries are installed here:
`%WINDIR%\Globalization\ELS\SpellDictionaries`

To obtain the dictionaries, you can try as follows:

- Download the MSU file containing the dictionary here:
  https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=2841134
- Extract the dictionary files from the MSU on the Command Line:

```
expand ie-spelling-*.msu -f:Windows6.3-KB2849696-x86.cab .
md ie-spelling
expand Windows6.3-KB2849696-x86.cab -f:mssp7*.* -r ie-spelling
```

- Copy the three files from the subdirectories in the `ie-spelling` directory to `%WINDIR%\Globalization\ELS\SpellDictionaries`

Comment: Sounds really good, since we found out that spell checking also doesn't work in HTML textareas. Since my client is part of a huge company, they are not allowed to do registry stuff on their own PCs. I recommended to get in touch with their help desk and proclaim that spell checking doesn't work on web forms. I'll get back her, once I've got an answer from my client.

Comment: @Windwalker, Let us know about the test result and the status of the issue once your client gets a chance to test it. It may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Sure I will get back, once my customer has the dictionary installed on his PC.