# CSS hyphens:auto does not work in microsoft-Edge

Tags: css, microsoft-edge, css-hyphens

Looking at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=hyphens), the CSS-attribute `hyphens:auto` should work in edge version 105 upwards. But, it doesnt - sometimes.

The following screenshot shows at the left hand side an testing html-file in firefox, an it shows well. On the right hand side we find edge version 108 without hyphenation. However on another system with edge version 110 it works perfectly, see second screenshot.

[image: screenshot firefox / edge 1080]
[image: screenshot edge 110]

- Is something wrong with our CSS or html?
- Is there a problem with Edge version 108, such that `hyphens:auto` is broken?
- Is there some hidden setting or magic flag in Edge to disable hyphenation, maybe some possibility for the admin of our organization to touch this?
- Or something completely different?

```css
body {
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:50%">
          <h1 lang="de">Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaftkapitän</h1>
        </th>
        <th style="width:50%">
          <h1 lang="en">A superextraordinarily long English word!</h1>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
  <div id="navigator" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("navigator").innerText = navigator.userAgent;
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Update:

Our organization updated Edge to version 110 - and hyphenation still does not work. So we have two systems with the same version and different behaviour of the hyphens.

Comment: It looks like edge to me

Comment: See also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64370853/4308751
The files mentioned there are present on my system

Answer (score 1):

On my newly-installed VM with Microsoft Edge and Google Chrome (both up to date), I have tested your code and interestingly the hyphens didn't show up (Firefox works as expected). Then, I think the issue may not be caused by any version not supporting `hyphens: auto`.

I successfully re-enabled the automatic hyphenation by manually checking for update of the **Hyphenation** component at **edge://components**. Also have done the same in Chrome and it works fine now. This, I believe, can serve as an inspiration for you.

Comment: We are not connected to the internet directly, so the `update` Button in edge://components does not work. Is there some link to download a single component?

Comment: @frifle, unfortunately we cannot update Edge/Chrome components like what we can do to IE/Edge Legacy with local files. As a workaround, you can use `hyphens: manual;` and `&shy;` (soft hyphen) to indicate a potential place to insert a hyphen. This will standardize the hyphen behavior on your systems.